# 6.13 LAB: Filter and sort a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting, filter

Write a program that gets a list of integers from input, and outputs non-negative integers in ascending order (lowest to highest).

Example: If the input is:

10 -7 4 39 -6 12 2

the output is:

2 4 10 12 39

My code that I came up with looks like this:

```
user_input = input()
numbers = user_input.split()

nums = []

for number in numbers:
    nums.append(int(number))
    
for item in nums:
    if int(item) < 0:
        nums.remove(item)
    
list.sort(nums)

for x in nums:
    print(x, end=' ')
```

It gives me an 8/10 for my score but on one of the input/outputs it gives me

input is -1 -7 -2 -88 5 -6
my output is -88 -7 5

Why is it only removing some of the negative numbers and not all of them?

Comment: Study: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating

Answer (score 0):

```
for item in nums:
    if int(item) < 0:
        nums.remove(item)
```

problem is probbably here, since you iterate thru a list for which you remove elements in the iterations of the for el in list loop.

You should just use list comprenhension to copy positive integers to a new list and return it.

So the return list would be:

```
onlyPositiveIntegers = [x for x in nums if x >= 0]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
nums.sort()    
for item in nums:
    if int(item) >= 0:
        break
    nums.remove(item)
print(*nums)
```

iterate only through -ve no. and remove them.